# Magento2: Issues with duplicate simple product

Tags: magento2, url, products, duplicate

I have duplicate a simple product.

The original simple product has:

- SKU: pld942
- URL: pld942.html

after duplicate:

- SKU: pld942-1
- URL: pld942-1.html

I set in duplicate product:

- enable
- weight
- qty
- in stock
- and then save and reindex

Still I not see this product. When I put url with duplicate product then 404 not found.

Any solution?

Comment: Can you see the duplicated product listed in a category?

Answer (score 0):

Just as part of diagnosing the issue, I would advise starting by saving the duplicate product before making any changes. Then make changes. See if this changes anything.

On the frontend. I would advise adding the product to a category/and or searching for it, and seeing if it appears, just in case it's a URL rewrite issue.